get the current quarter in DAX
I have a code as below. The month May should be in Quarter 1 = QUARTER(TODAY()) but QUARTER('Calendar'[Date]) seems not producing the same output. Is there a reason for that? many thanks in advance.
 get_current_quarter = 

IF(
    AND(
    QUARTER(TODAY()) = QUARTER('Calendar'[Date]),
    YEAR(TODAY()) = YEAR('Calendar'[Date])
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)


why should May be in quarter 1?

in may dataset, fiscal year starts from May.

Based on the answer I provided here, you can add a calculated column where you consider that your fiscal year starts from May of each year :
IsCurrentQuarter = 
VAR CurrentDate = TODAY()
VAR CurrentMonth = MONTH(CurrentDate)
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(CurrentDate)
VAR CurrentFiscalYear = IF(CurrentMonth >= 5, CurrentYear, CurrentYear - 1)
VAR CurrentFiscalQuarter = SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    CurrentMonth >= 5 && CurrentMonth <= 7, 1,
    CurrentMonth >= 8 && CurrentMonth <= 10, 2,
    CurrentMonth >= 11 && CurrentMonth <= 1, 3,
    CurrentMonth >= 2 && CurrentMonth <= 4, 4
)
RETURN
    IF (
        [Fiscal Year] = CurrentFiscalYear &&
        [Fiscal Quarter] = CurrentFiscalQuarter,
        "Yes",
        "No"
    )


Same for June and July :


Different for August which belongs to the 2nd quarter of the fiscal year and is not current comparing to the current date :

